# What is wrong with my BlogPosting code? "Missing '}' or object member name."

Tags: json, validation, schema.org, json-ld

I've been working on this `BlogPosting` schema, and I run it through the Google testing tool and I keep seeing an error message at the very end:

> [image: JSON-LD error: "Missing '}' or object member name."]

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
    { 
     "@context": "http://schema.org", 
     "@type": "BlogPosting",
     "mainentityofpage": "https://www.northcountrylaw.com",
     "headline": "14 Ways Json Can Improve Your SEO",
     "alternativeHeadline": "and the women who love them",
     "image": "http://example.com/image.jpg",
     "award": "Best article ever written",
     "editor": "John Doe", 
     "genre": "search engine optimization", 
     "keywords": "seo sales b2b", 
     "wordcount": "1120",
      "Publisher": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "Cat's Meow",
        "logo": {
                "@type": "ImageObject",
                "name": "Cats cats cats",
                "width": "1024",
                "height": "1024",
                "url": "https://www.greatcats.png"
                     }
        },
    "url": "http://www.example.com",
    "datePublished": "2015-09-20",
     "dateCreated": "2015-09-20",
     "dateModified": "2015-09-20",
     "description": "We love to do stuff to help people and stuff",
     "articleBody": "You can paste your entire post in here, and yes it can get really really long.",
       "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "kitten boots"
     },
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### JSON-LD errors

- You have four `{`, but only three `}`.
- You have a `,` after the last `}`, but nothing follows.

So, you have to remove the comma and close the `author`:

```json
 "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "kitten boots"
    }
 }
```

#### Schema.org errors

Schema.org terms are case-sensitive. It has to be:

- `publisher` instead of `Publisher`
- `mainEntityOfPage` instead of `mainentityofpage`
- `wordCount` instead of `wordcount`

Comment: Thank you so much!  I'm still learning and really appreciate your help!

Comment: @KimberlySCummins: If it answered your question, you can [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to mark your question as solved.